# Substituting millions of regular expressions (perl)

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have a text file containing over one million lines of text. On each line, there is an alphanumerical code which needs to be substituted with a name. I have tried doing this using different Perl scripts, but each time the scripts die because they are using too many memory. I am new to Perl, so I imagine that I am doing something wrong, and it making the job too complex?
So far, I have tried:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'names.txt';

my $data = read_file($filename);

$data =~ s/88tx0p/Author1/g;
##and then there are 1,000,000+ other substitution regexes.

write_file($filename, $data);
exit;

sub read_file {
my ($filename) = @_;

open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename or die "Could not open 
'$filename' for reading $!";
local $/ = undef;
my $all = <$in>;
close $in;

return $all;
}

sub write_file {
my ($filename, $content) = @_;

open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename or die "Could not open 
'$filename' for writing $!";;
print $out $content;
close $out;

return;
}
```

But then I realised that this script is trying to write the output to the original file, which I imagine uses more memory? So I tried the following:

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

open(FILE, 'names.txt') || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my @newlines;
foreach(@lines) {
$_ =~ s/88tx0p/Author1/g;
##and then there are approximately 1,000,000 other substitution regexes.
push(@newlines,$_);
}

open(FILE, '>names_edited.txt') || die "File not found";
;
print FILE @newlines;
close(FILE);
```

But again, this used too much memory. Please could I get help with ways of doing this while using minimum amount of memory? Thank you all.

Comment: Process the file line by line instead of slurping it all into memory.

Comment: Do you mean that your script is over 1,000,000 lines long, with a million different  s/// patterns, or do you mean that the one single regex is applied to all 1 million lines?

Comment: @DaveMitchell The former. Each line has a different substitution pattern associated with it. Apologies for the ambiguity!

Comment: In that case the excessive memory usage probably comes from having a million separate regexes. Is the alphanumerical code on each line in a well-defined format? In which case you could store the codes and names in a hash, then have a single regex of the form, e.g.,  s/\b(\d+[a-z]+\d\w)\b/$names{$1}/g

Comment: @DaveMitchell Ah, okay - I will give that a go, thanks! Just to double check would I make the codes the hash keys and then the associated names the hash values?

Comment: yes. The pattern should be such that it matches only codes and nothing else. If there is a chance that there will be matched things that aren't codes (i.e. don't exist in the hash), then the substitution needs to be more complex, e.g.

Comment: (continued) s{....}{$names{$1}//$1}ge

Comment: @DaveMitchell Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is you're using a `foreach` loop. That needs you to load all the lines into memory, which is the root of your problem.

Try it in a while loop:

```perl
open ( my $file, '<', 'names.txt' ) or die $!; 
open ( my $output, '>', 'names_edited.txt' ) or die $!;
select $output; #destination for print; 
while ( <$file> ) {  #reads one line at a time, sets $_
    s/88tx0p/Author1/g;   #acts on $_ by default
    print; #defaults to printing $_ to the selected filehandle $output
}
```

That'll work line by line (as your initial code was) but will read only one line at a time, so the memory footprint will be vastly lower.